# Add a security group to running instance using Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

How can I add a new security group to a running instance without removing existing ones using Ansible?

I tried ec2 module but that doesn't look like changing anything even if I pass a new security group with instance id.

Any help please?

Comment: can you give an example of the ec2 play you are using?

Comment: There was a feature request for this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18928

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support for it in ansible. If you have `AWS CLI` installed, use **shell** module to modify the SG. You **must** specify all security groups.

```
- shell: aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-12345678 --groups sg-old-123def sg-new-abc123
```

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I'm doing as a workaround that is again leading to various other exceptions. Wondering if there's any Ansible way for it but looks like there isn't as of now.

Comment: Ansible cannot support every aspect of EC2. If there is no support, use the CLI. WHat exceptions are you getting

Comment: problem occurs when there are more than one security groups attached to a running instance. For e.g. group 'a' and 'b' are attached to instance and I want to add 'c'. First I'll fetch the list of existing groups and add my third one to the list and pass it on to CLI however, the list that I fetch contains groups in format like 'sg-a\nsg-b'. Now the problem is how to handle '\n' and replace with ',' to pass it on to CLI.

Comment: I was searching for this today myself. I used to have a ruby script that did the same thing. But I borrowed that from a DevOps guy in the past. I am looking to achieve the same with Ansible or Boto. @ankittyagi if you have any code to share I can help!

Comment: @shdobxr see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352349/boto3-attach-detach-security-group-from-ec2-instance. Make sure to upvote if it answers the question.

Comment: 10-4 @helloV you are quite the stackoverflow machine!!!

My need was for supplying a boto/python script a list of instances... then state what SG's to remove (if any) then what SG's to apply (if any) to make SG application much easier. Your's is close but nice precisely what I am looking for.