# Attach / Detach Security Group from EC2 instance using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

How can I go about disassociating a particular security group from all EC2 instances and then associate it with a new EC2 instance, with `boto3`?

I'm trying something like:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter()
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
    for sg in instance.security_groups:
    if sg['GroupId'] == sg_id:
        instance.modify_attribute ???
```

Comment: It is recommended to tag all your security group, and use describe_security_groups.filter  to get the correctly tagged security_group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
  instances = ec2.instances.filter()
  for instance in instances:
     print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
     all_sg_ids = [sg['GroupId'] for sg in instance.security_groups]  # Get a list of ids of all securify groups attached to the instance
     if sg_id in all_sg_ids:                                          # Check the SG to be removed is in the list
       all_sg_ids.remove(sg_id)                                       # Remove the SG from the list
       instance.modify_attribute(Groups=all_sg_ids)                   # Attach the remaining SGs to the instance
```

Comment: Thanks @helloV -- I have the modify_attribute in my code above. The part I'm having trouble grasping is, what logic do I need to get the instances' current groups (it might have a few assigned) and then remove only the one group in question, leaving the other groups attached.

Comment: @DrewOConnor check my solution. Add a print statement in between (or run it in a Python shell) to understand how it works.

Comment: Anyone know how to remove all groups? If I use Groups=[] I get InvalidParameterCombination